# CoreValidation-DrawState-InvalidImageLayout error on submited command buffer

Tags: c++, vulkan

i can't figure why i get this error

> Message:  [ UNASSIGNED-CoreValidation-DrawState-InvalidImageLayout ] Object: 0x55f38f345890 (Type = 6) | Submitted command buffer expects image 0x1e (subresource: aspectMask 0x1 array layer 0, mip level 0) to be in layout VK_IMAGE_LAYOUT_COLOR_ATTACHMENT_OPTIMAL--instead, image 0x1e's current layout is VK_IMAGE_LAYOUT_PRESENT_SRC_KHR.

i'm using a command buffer to blit an image from a framebuffer to the current present image like this

```
    command_buffer.transitionImageLayout(
  framebuffer_image, ImageLayout::COLOR_ATTACHMENT_OPTIMAL, ImageLayout::TRANSFERT_SRC_OPTIMAL);

command_buffer.transitionImageLayout(
  current_image, ImageLayout::PRESENT_SRC, ImageLayout::TRANSFERT_DST_OPTIMAL);

command_buffer.blitImage(
  framebuffer_image, current_image, framebuffer_image.extent(), m_extent);

command_buffer.transitionImageLayout(
  framebuffer_image, ImageLayout::TRANSFERT_SRC_OPTIMAL, ImageLayout::COLOR_ATTACHMENT_OPTIMAL);

command_buffer.transitionImageLayout(
  current_image, ImageLayout::TRANSFERT_DST_OPTIMAL, ImageLayout::PRESENT_SRC);
```

the error is fired on command buffer submit

i activated the VK_LAYER_LUNARG_api_dump layer and i obtain this:

https://pastebin.com/AFyePUpM

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The error message is pretty straightforward.

You first use the image as `VK_IMAGE_LAYOUT_COLOR_ATTACHMENT_OPTIMAL` in the command buffer. We can see and verify that:

`command_buffer.transitionImageLayout( framebuffer_image, ImageLayout::COLOR_ATTACHMENT_OPTIMAL // etc`

The error informs you that the image is in the `VK_IMAGE_LAYOUT_PRESENT_SRC_KHR` instead. How that happened depends on the rest of your code. You must have transitioned the image to that layout before (accidentally). That would be either via some previous `vkCmdPipelineBarrier`, or via renderpass `finalLayout`.

(Or less likely there's a bug in the Validation Layers. In which case report it to [KhronosGroup/Vulkan-ValidationLayers](https://github.com/KhronosGroup/Vulkan-ValidationLayers/issues).)

Answer (score 0):

Is your `framebuffer_image` coming from a swapchain image? If yes, seems it is still in `VK_IMAGE_LAYOUT_PRESENT_SRC_KHR` layout -- that issue can probably be fixed by changing your first line.

Comment: framebuffer_image is not coming from my swapchain

Comment: How does it get created then? What's in `VkAttachmentDescription.initialLayout` and `.finalLayout`?